# Get List Of Google Analytics integrated Application by gmail Account

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I want to get the list of google analytics integrated applications with my gmail account. whether google providing any API for getting the list of applications and its view id? is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you looking for the set of [applications that integrate Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/partners/search/apps)? Or are you looking for the [list of applications](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) you authorized to access your Analytics Data? If you expond on your use case it might help folks understand what you are attempting to do.

Comment: i am looking into list of application which are added google analytics. which i can see in this link. https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#home/a69358788w108051594p112595509/

Comment: OH... you are looking for your Google Analytics account summary. The complete list of [Accounts, Properties and Views](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618) What you need to do is call the [account summaries list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google account (gmail account) can be associated with many [Google Analytics Accounts, Properties and Views](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618).

In order to retrieve the full list of these entities you need to callthe [account summaries list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) method.

```
/**
 * Example #1:
 * Requests a list of all account summaries for the authorized user.
 */
try {
  AccountSummaries accountSummaries = service.management().
      accountSummaries().list().execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
}
```